# Can't show / hide an element by Id in WinJS / Windows Store Apps

Tags: jquery, css, windows-store-apps, winjs

I have a WinJS app. I'm trying to show / hide a panel on the settings screen. Through trial and error I've discovered this can't be done via the id, only the class.

None of the following works

```
$("#CustomPanel").show()
$("#CustomPanel").toggle(true)
$("#CustomPanel").css("display", "block");
$("#CustomPanel").attr("style", "display:block;");
$("#CustomPanel")[0].setAttribute("style", "display:block;");
document.getElementById("CustomPanel").setAttribute("style", "display:block;");
```

However this *does* work:

```
$(".CustomPanel").show();
```

Why is this? I would expect to be able to affect elements by Id within a WinJS app. Is this some glitch to do with setting flyouts?

## UPDATE - added HTML / JS

/html/settings.html

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Options flyout</title>
        <script src="/js/settings.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
    <div data-win-control="WinJS.UI.SettingsFlyout" aria-label="Options flyout"
         data-win-options="{settingsCommandId:'settings',width:'wide'}">
        <div class="win-ui-dark win-header" style="background-color:#00b2f0">
            <button type="button" 
             onclick="WinJS.UI.SettingsFlyout.show()" class="win-backbutton"></button>
            <div class="win-label">Options</div>
        </div>
        <div class="win-content">
            <div class="win-settings-section" id="settingsscreen">
                <h3>Themes</h3>
                <select id="selectTheme">
                    <option value="default">Default</option>
                    <option value="custom">Custom Theme</option>
                </select>

                <div id="CustomThemePanel" style="display: none;">
                    I'm never visible
                </div>

                <div class="CustomThemePanel" style="display: none;">
                    I toggle correctly 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

/js/settings.js

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    
    var applicationData = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current;
    var localSettings = applicationData.localSettings;

    var page = WinJS.UI.Pages.define("/html/settings.html", {
        ready: function (element, options)
        {
            var _selectedTheme = localSettings.values["selectedTheme"] || "default";
            $(document).on("change", "#selectTheme", function (e) {
                localSettings.values["selectedTheme"] = _selectedTheme = this.value;
                if (_selectedTheme == "custom"){
                    $("#CustomThemePanel").show();
                    $(".CustomThemePanel").show();
                }else{
                    $("#CustomThemePanel").hide();
                    $(".CustomThemePanel").hide();
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

If I log the value of `_selectedTheme` to the console, I can see it changes from `true` to `false` as the dropdown state is changed. Stranger still, if I inspect the style of `CustomThemePanel` at either stage, it shows the css *does* change, it just doesn't get rendered.

Comment: $("#CustomPanel").show(); should work , share the HTML

Comment: shared the html, see updated question

Comment: You are aware that `id` **must** be unique per document?

Comment: @connexo yes. CustomThemePanel is declared as an id in the first div and a class in the second

Comment: Your code works on my machine, I loaded your code in a new VS2013 project, added a reference to jQuery and toggling the drop down list displayed the "I'm never visible" panel.

Comment: @a7drew it must be some problem in my project then. thanks for trying